# How to blur the div after 2 seconds using Angular 12 and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add the blur class for div after 2 seconds. after that I have to display some values to that div. I don't know how to do this in angular and typescript. Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+blur+div+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[ngClass]` in order to dynamically add a class depending of the value of a variable :

```html
<!-- Dynamically add the class "blurred" on the element if isBlurred is true -->

<div [ngClass]="{ blurred: isBlurred }">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

More about `NgClass` : [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Then, in Typescript, use a `setTimeout` :

```js
isBlurred = false;
[...]

setTimeout(() => this.isBlurred = true, 2000);
```

Then, express your creativity in CSS :p

```
.blurred {
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

See StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uaybqt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Without more context.. try this.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   setTimeout( ()=>{
   // set class here
   }, 2000)
 }
```

This will add a timeout when the component gets initiated (lifecycle hook). After 2000 milliseconds it will run the javascript that you define, ie the setting of a class.